# Cosmos (C# OS): running on Azure?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, operating-system

I've been looking around and doing some Googling to try and find out if you can run Cosmos, the C# operating system, on Windows Azure.

Ideally, I'd like to use it to run singular instances of applications, such as websites or a service/data layers. They'd be scalable and report back to the load balancing instances, etc.

Haven't managed to find anything through my (albeit somewhat limited) research. Any ideas, knowledge or suggestions as to what I should do about this? Also, some general pointers about my idea above would be more than welcome and appreciated.

Let me know if you need any further detail. I haven't asked many questions on here.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, no, I wouldn't count on Azure ever giving the option to boot another operating system.

Comment: You should read the news: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-to-enable-linux-on-its-windows-azure-cloud-in-2012/11508

Comment: Oh, apparently they already have VM support, it's just that they can be scrapped and recycled at any time... which is *precisely* what I want. :P Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VM Role only supports Windows Server 2008 R2 as the operating system. The Windows Azure Integration Components which are required to interact with the Fabric Controller are specific to Server 2008 R2.

This means even if you were to install the OS in a VM Role, you would not have the ability to hook the VM instance into Windows Azure.

I'm not sure if any other cloud provider would be able to support this functionality either, but I would love to hear more about it if you are able to figure it out.

Comment: Ah, okay. A shame. I don't massively like how Azure boxes you into specific ways of doing things and apparently it's near impossible to implement a custom load balancing solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ryan Dunn (Formerly of Microsoft) explains how to do Sticky HTTP Session on Windows Azure... You could check it out on channel9. https://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-24-Routing-in-Windows-Azure/

Comment: There's a better way of doing sticky session load balancing, as described here: http://coderead.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/using-azurearr-sticky-sessions-in-azure/

Answer (score -1):

There is no native support for COSMOS, but you *could* install it on a virtual machine on an Azure box (which is already a VM). I don't this is a very good idea.

Comment: I think i just got your point, but it still wouldn't work. Hyper-V isn't enabled in Windows Azure, even if it was it would be extremely difficult to do what James is asking above.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I'm suggesting the rather horrible solution of installing something like VirtualBox on an Azure instance, and then putting COSMOS on that.